# how to join the same table to get difference of price between two days?

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a table "Product" where I have a price of products day wise, now I want to know which are the products which are missing from today which were present yesterday, and if in both day they were present and what is the difference in price change.

For example table "Products":

```
locale     productID        price         date
US         pro1             100           2015-04-02
US         pro2             200           2015-04-02
CA         pro1             100           2015-04-02

US         pro1             110           2015-04-01
US         pro3             500           2015-04-01
CA         pro4             100           2015-04-01
```

So the desired output should be:-

```
locale_t|productID_t|price_t|date_t|locale_y|productID_y|price_y|date_y|change
US       pro1        100   2015-04-02  US    pro1        110   2015-04-01   10
US       pro2        200   2015-04-02        REMOVED                       200
         REMOVED                       US    pro3        500   2015-04-01  500
CA       pro1        100   2015-04-02        REMOVED                       100
         REMOVED                       CA    pro4        100               100
```

where locale_t means locale_today and locale_y means locale_yesterday.
So I can clearly tell how many products are removed from yesterday and how many added today.

Answer (score 1):

You want a self-cross-join, but it's complicated by the fact that you're really joining two distinct subsets.

To achieve this, one way is to join on two subqueries over the same data, e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2d6ae/15 :

```sql
SELECT 
  coalesce(yesterday.locale, today.locale) AS locale,
  coalesce(yesterday."productID", today."productID") AS "productID",
  today.date AS date_t,
  today.price AS price_t,
  yesterday.date AS date_y,
  yesterday.price AS price_y,
  today.price - yesterday.price AS "change"
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE "date" = '2015-04-01'
  ) AS yesterday
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE "date" = '2015-04-02'
  ) AS today
  ON (today."locale" = yesterday."locale"
      AND today."productID" = yesterday."productID")
 ORDER BY 1, 2;

 locale | productID |   date_t   | price_t |   date_y   | price_y | change 
--------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+---------+--------
 CA     | pro1      | 2015-04-02 |     100 |            |         |       
 CA     | pro4      |            |         | 2015-04-01 |     100 |       
 US     | pro1      | 2015-04-02 |     100 | 2015-04-01 |     110 |    -10
 US     | pro2      | 2015-04-02 |     200 |            |         |       
 US     | pro3      |            |         | 2015-04-01 |     500 |       
(5 rows)
```

The expected results aren't exactly the same, but you didn't really make any attempt to specify in words what you wanted and I didn't feel like guessing.

I suspect you will probably want to use `coalesce` in the `change` column to produce results for null, something like:

```
coalesce(today.price - yesterday.price, today.price, -yesterday.price) AS "change"
```